# Why are google maps crashing my Expo-built android app?

Tags: android, react-native, google-maps, expo

I am working on a react-native/expo app, that displays the google map.

```
            <MapView
                googleMapsApiKey={process.env.EXPO_GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY}
                style={styles.map}
                ref={_map}
                showsUserLocation={true}
                showsMyLocationButton={true}
                minZoomLevel={0}
                maxZoomLevel={20}
                region={{
                    ...marker,
                    latitudeDelta: 0.016,
                    longitudeDelta: 0.003,
                }}
                camera={{
                    ...marker,
                    zoom: 0,
                    altitude: 0,
                    pitch: 0,
                    heading: 0,
                }}
            >
```

All works in development mode, but after building it in expo, it crashes every time I try to open the map:

```json
    "preview": {
      "env": {
        "EXPO_GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY":" [api key string] "
      },
      "developmentClient":false,
      "android": {
        "buildType": "apk"
      }
        }
```

Could the issue be in a wrong api key? I am using the Maps JavaScript API...

Comment: Can you please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that demonstrates this crash? So that the community can check for themselves and see what might have gone wrong. Also is there any error you can log during crash?

Answer (score 0):

Google Maps crashes in your Expo-built Android app could be due to issues such as an invalid API key, package/version compatibility, permissions, Gradle configuration, Expo SDK version, network problems, or caching. Check these factors, review error logs, and ensure proper configurations to resolve the crashes.

Comment: passed the expo-doctor. no issues in other logs. still, it crashes...

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).